# Yahoo! email signup without mobile phone

Tags: yahoo-mail, yahoo-account

How do I sign up for a Yahoo! email account without a mobile phone? Can't afford one on SSD.

Answer (score 3):

Now it is not possible to create an Yahoo! account without phone number. They have made it mandatory field to sign up for Yahoo!.

From the [Yahoo! help](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account/sign-yahoo-account-sln2056.html?impressions=true):

> **Important:** Your registration will not process without a [valid mobile number](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account/valid-mobile-number-sln14992.html).